# Не приходят ообщения из формы обратной связи

Tags: php, post, html-form, отправка

PHP не знаю, к сожалению. Пытаюсь прикрутить к сайту готовую форму, код которой нашла в сети. И сообщения не приходят, увы. Было только тестовое сообщение с сайта-источника, подтверждающее, что все работает. Это мозга мне не хватает.
В html пишу:

```
<div class="ddd">
  <form name="MyForm" action="http://baseflat.ru/mail.php" method="post" >
    <p><input class="input" name="name" type="text" style="width:35%;min-width: 140px; max-width: 350px;" /> Ваше имя*</p>
    <p><input class="input" name="phone" type="text" style="width:35%;min-width: 140px; max-width: 350px;" /> Телефон*</p>
    <p><input class="input" name="email" type="text" style="width:35%;  min-width: 140px; max-width: 350px;" /> Эл. почта*</p>
    <p>Текст сообщения:<br /><textarea name="body" cols="1" rows="5" style="width:50%;  min-width: 250px; max-width: 850px;" /></textarea></p>
    <p><input id="submit" value="Отправить" type="submit" /></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

В файле mail.php такое содержание:

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5; url=http://www.baseflat.ru/'>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name']; if ($name == '') {unset($name);}}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; if ($email == '') {unset($email);}}
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {$sub = $_POST['sub']; if ($sub == '') {unset($sub);}}
if (isset($_POST['body'])) {$body = $_POST['body']; if ($body == '') {unset($body);}}

if (isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($sub) && isset($body)) {
   $address = "kv7151408@yandex.ru";
   $mes = "Имя: $name \nE-mail: $email \nТема: $sub \nТекст: $body";
   $send = mail ($address, $sub, $mes, "Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");

   if ($send == 'true') {
      echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно, через 5 секунд Вы будете направлены на главную страницу сайта <a href='http://www.baseflat.ru/</a>,где сможете продолжить просмотр";
   } else {
      echo "Ошибка, сообщение не отправлено!";
   }
} else {
   echo "Вы заполнили не все поля, вернитесь назад и заполните необходимые поля";
}
?>
```

Подскажите, что нужно исправить? Сервер поддерживает php. А я пока - нет :(
Спасибо!
P.S. Никакого сообщения об ошибке/отправке и т.п. не получаю. Просто обновляется страница, и всё.

Файл.log я, таки, нашла. Его сюда копировать? 
Error.log - пустые файлы. access.log - много каких-то данных, в которых я ничего не понимаю.

В папке "Спам" тоже нет писем.

Comment: 1. уберите meta теги из файла mail.php 2. что в логах?

Comment: isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($sub) && isset($body) у вас это обязательные поля. Судя по форме у вас нету инпута sub

Comment: Обычная проблема, тут таких вопросов по 2-3 в неделю. Что бы `mail` функция работала должен быть настроено приложение которое его отправляет. Если это shared hosting то оно отключено(что бы не спамили). Есть вариант отровлять через своего почтового провайдера (SMTP), используйте библиотеку типа https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. Или через сервис типа mailchimp.

Comment: попробуйте заменить строчку isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($sub) && isset($body) на isset($name) && isset($email) &&  isset($body)

Comment: Ну и код копировать не зная что он делает это плохо, Можно проблем споймать немало.

Comment: Замена строки по совету Константина не помогла, к сожалению. Про отправку через приложение, - мне нужна отправка непосредственно с сервера. У меня значится метод post, а не mail

Comment: Что нужно посмотреть в логах? Найти файл - нашла, что искать в нем - не знаю. Error.log - пустые файлы. access.log - много каких-то данных, в которых я ничего не понимаю

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="ddd">
<form name="MyForm" action="http://baseflat.ru/mail.php" method="post" >
    <p><input class="input" name="name" type="text" style="width:35%;min-width: 140px; max-width: 350px;" /> Ваше имя*</p>
    <p><input class="input" name="phone" type="text" style="width:35%;min-width: 140px; max-width: 350px;" /> Телефон</p>
    <p><input class="input" name="email" type="text" style="width:35%;  min-width: 140px; max-width: 350px;" /> Эл. почта*</p>
    <p><input class="input" name="sub" type="text" style="width:35%;min-width: 140px; max-width: 350px;" /> Тема сообщения*</p>
    <p>Текст сообщения*:<br />
        <textarea name="body" cols="1" rows="5" style="width:50%;  min-width: 250px; max-width: 850px;" /></textarea>
    </p>
    <p><input id="submit" value="Отправить" type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; if($name == ''){ unset($name);}}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $email = $_POST['email']; if($email == ''){ unset($email);}}
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){ $sub = $_POST['sub']; if($sub == ''){ unset($sub);}}
if(isset($_POST['body'])){ $body = $_POST['body']; if($body == ''){ unset($body);}}
if(isset($_POST['phone'])){ $phone = $_POST['phone']; if($phone == ''){ unset($phone);}}

if(isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($sub) && isset($body))
{
 $address = "kv7151408@yandex.ru";

 if(isset($phone))
 {
  $mes = "Имя: $name\nE-mail: $email\nТелефон: $phone\nТема: $sub\nТекст: $body";
 }
 else
 {
  $mes = "Имя: $name\nE-mail: $email\nТема: $sub\nТекст: $body";
 }

 $mailheaders  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $mailheaders .= "From: $email <$email>\r\n"; 
 $mailheaders .= "Reply-To: noreply\r\n"; 

 $address = '<'.$address.'>';

 try
 {
  mail($address, $sub, $mes, $mailheaders);
  echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно, через 5 секунд Вы будете направлены на главную страницу сайта <a href='http://www.baseflat.ru/</a>,где сможете продолжить просмотр.";
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }
}
else
{
 echo "Вы заполнили не все поля, вернитесь назад и заполните необходимые поля";
}
?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54668/discussion-on-answer-by-kivydin-------).